# Context data not rendering variable to HTML

Tags: html, mysql, django

I have a dropdown menu where the user can select the orderID of a taxi ride, and the total distance travelled for that specific order ID will be rendered to the html. The total distance is already in my MySQL database and only needs to be rendered to the frontend, but I'm calling the variable and its not working. I've managed to get it to print to the terminal, but it's showing on my html file and I'm pretty sure I'm calling the variable wrong. Everything else renders, just not `{{ total_distance}}`. Any pointers?

[image]

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    # limit query results to first 50 orders just to maximise performance
    orders = Distance.objects.all().order_by("order")[:50]

    if request.method == "POST":  # code only enters if statement when an item from the dropdown menu is selected
        print("POST")
        order_id_selected = request.POST.get("order_id_selected", None)
        if order_id_selected:
            start_lat = Distance.objects.values_list(
                'start_lat').filter(order_id__exact=order_id_selected)
            start_long = Distance.objects.values_list(
                'start_long').filter(order_id__exact=order_id_selected)
            end_lat = Distance.objects.values_list(
                'end_lat').filter(order_id__exact=order_id_selected)
            end_long = Distance.objects.values_list(
                'end_long').filter(order_id__exact=order_id_selected)

            total_distance = Distance.objects.values_list(
                'total_distance').filter(order_id__exact=order_id_selected)
            print(order_id_selected)
            print(total_distance)
            
        return render(request, 'base.html', {
            'orders': orders,
            'dropdown_menu': order_id_selected,
            'total_distance': total_distance,
        })
    else:  # current view defaults to else
        print("not working")
        return render(request, 'base.html', {
            'orders': orders,
        })
```

**base.html**

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-9">
            <div class="order">
                <br>
                <h2>View and calculate distance per order</h2>
                <select name="dropdown_menu" id="dropdown_menu">
                    <option class="dropdown" type="dropdown" selected>-- Select Order ID -- </option>
                    {% for order in orders %}
                    <!-- for x in {context}-->
                    <option value="{{ order.order_id }}"> {{ order.order_id }} </option>
                    {% endfor %}
        
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>

                <p>The total distance for the selected order is __ {{ total_distance }} km</p>
                <!-- render distance calculation -->
                <!-- render distance on folium -->
            </div>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
            <script>
                $("#dropdown_menu").change(function () { // calling select id
                    const order_id_selected = $(this).val();  // get the selected subject ID from the HTML dropdown list 
                    $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '',
                        data: {
                            'order_id_selected': order_id_selected,       // add the order id to the POST parameters
                            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{csrf_token}}",
                            // 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                        },
                        success: function (data) {   // `data` is from `homepage` view function
                            let html_data = '<option value="">---------</option>';
                            data.forEach(function (data) {
                                html_data += `<option value="${data.id}">${data.title}</option>`
                            });
                            $("#dropdown_menu").html(html_data); // replace the contents of the topic input with the data that came from the server
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
          </div>
```

Comment: can you check total_distance type ??? i think total distance is return queryset object  and not value  .

Comment: `total_distance = Distance.objects.values_list(
                'total_distance').filter(order_id__exact=order_id_selected)` is return list of values of queryset.  Is  `order_id` unique?

Comment: @Meet yes total_distance is a valueslistqueryset. i've had a fair share of difficulty trying to convert django wrapper classes to floats (but can convert to string), does that have to be done?

Comment: @koko `order_id` is unique

Comment: Could you show Distance model?

Comment: @koko thanks for the help, but it seems like the issue is with the success portion of the AJAX handling

Comment: @cookiestarninja your just need to convert that list into single value . or else you can index list into your template ex. {{ total_distance.0 }} . but that's not good idea you can first indexing element in your view and after parse to context .

Comment: I asked about Model because I wanted to get example. I agree with @Meet, that you have `total_distance` as multi value variable. I think you should overwrite logic for this variable. Try something like `total_distance = Distance.objects.get(order_id=order_id_selected).<field_name_where_your_value>`

Comment: thanks for the help! i've managed to fix it and it came down to several things - since my POST request goes to `dropdown_menu`, i got rid of `render` and changed it to JsonResponse, which returned just `total_distance` alone. i also converted `total_distance` to a float and used @Abhishek Sahu's answer for the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

```
        return render(request, 'base.html', {
            'orders': orders,
            'dropdown_menu': order_id_selected,
            'total_distance': total_distance,
        })
```

The return of POST is the original template but inserted at the id **dropdown_menu**.
However, you probably only need the total_distance to be returned for the selected **order_id_selected**.

In views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
if request.method == "POST":
    ###### same as yours ####
    return HttpResponse(f"The total distance for the selected order is __ {total_distance} km")
```

In the template, add id to the

tag

```
<p id='output'>The total distance for the selected order is __ {{ total_distance }} km</p>
```

Replace this success function of ajax with

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#output").text(data);
};
```

Comment: thanks for this, but it didn't work :/ no error messages either, which doesn't really help

Comment: Could you check the browser console for any error? Also, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html may be this could help.